# InvalidArgumentException View [admin\layouts\adminpanel] not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, admin

i am facing an issue with my admin page in laravel project, now everything is working well on localhost without any issue but when i upload to cpanel i faced this issue when i try to open " admin page "

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKuJz.png)

this is code of login.blade.php

```
@extends('admin\layouts\adminpanel')
@section('title') 
{{ __('title.adminLogin') }}
@stop
@section('links')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{{ asset('css\admin\login.css') }}"/>
@stop
@section('content')
<div class="contianer">
    <form method="post" class="login-form" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}" >
        @csrf
        @method('POST')
        <header> {{ __('headers.admin-login-form') }} </header>
        <section><img src="{{ asset('images/static/adminLogin.png') }}" /></section>
        <section>
            <input id="usernameInput"  type="text" {{ session()->has('invaild') ? 'class=input-invalid' :  '' }} name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="{{ __('input.email') }}" required />
            <input id="passwordInput" type="password" {{ session()->has('invaild') ? 'class=input-invalid' :  '' }} name="password" placeholder=" {{ __('input.password') }}" required />
            <input type="submit" formmethod="post" value="{{ __('input.loginButton') }}" />
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
@if(session()->has('invaild')) @php session()->remove('invaild') 
@endphp 
@endif
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" src="{{ asset('js\admin\login.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

i already check that the file " adminpanel " inisde layout is available and valid ...

what is the problem with cpanel even on localhost is working well ?

Need Your Help Please ..

Comment: try running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @Donkarnash how to run this on cpanel ?

Comment: From terminal - do you have terminal access? If you don't have terminal access then you can manually delete all compiled files from `/storage/framework/views` directory

Answer (score 1):

`\` is directory separator for windows and on a Unix-like system (including Mac OS X and Linux) is `/`. and on laravel you can also use `.` for directory separator on views.

so change

```
@extends('admin\layouts\adminpanel')
```

to

```
@extends('admin.layouts.adminpanel')
```

or

```
@extends('admin/layouts/adminpanel')
```

And also make sure `resources/views/admin/layouts/adminpanel.blade.php` is exist.

Comment: Great Answer ! thank you very much ... so now for all files in ADMIN folder i must do the same changes ??

Comment: yes you need to change all extends or include on all views and also controller. change to `.` for multi OS directory separator